# Custom linked list const_iterator cannot traverse non-const instance of list

Tags: c++, iterator

As an exercise in learning C++, I'm trying to write a custom iterator for a linked list.

Nodes in the list are added using the following `struct`:

```
template <class T> struct Node {
  T val;
  Node* next;
  Node* prev;
  Node(const T& new_val): val(new_val), next(0), prev(0) { }
};
```

And here are the relevant parts of the iterator:

```
template <class T> class LList_iterator {
public:
  //...
  LList_iterator(Node<T>* p): node(p) { }
  //...
private:
  Node<T>* node;
};
```

The linked list provides a `typedef` for both an `iterator` and a `const_iterator`:

```
template <class T> class LList {
public:
  typedef LList_iterator<T> iterator;
  typedef LList_iterator<const T> const_iterator;

  iterator begin() { return iterator(head); }
  const_iterator cbegin() const { return const_iterator(head); }

  iterator end() { return iterator(0); }
  const_iterator cend() const { return const_iterator(0); }
  //...
private:
  Node<T>* head;
};
```

I'm can use `iterator` correctly, but the compiler throws an error whenever I call the constructor of `const_iterator` and pass a pointer to the first node in the (non-const) linked list (when I call `cbegin()` and `cend()`):

```
LList<int> l;
l.push_back(10);
for (LList<int>::const_iterator i = l.cbegin(); i != l.cend(); ++i)
  std::cout << *i << std::endl;
```

> error: no matching functional-style cast from `Node<int> *const`
>   to `LList<int>::const_iterator` (aka `LList_iterator<const int>`)

I believe this could be because the `Node` type expected by `const_iterator` (**`const int`**) is different than the type in the list I am traversing (of type `int`).  If this is the case, is there any way for me to "temporarily" convert the `LList` template parameter to be `const int`?  Or am I misguided in my understanding of the error?

Comment: `Node<T>` is indeed completely unrelated to `Node<const T>` and is the reason of your error. Most of the time the solution is to bite the bullet and rewrite an entire iterator class for the const case.

Comment: Or, maybe you could have 1 iterator class with 2 template paarameters - 1 for the Node data type (`T`), and 1 for the iterator's `value_type` (`T` or `const T`) that operators act on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to do this:

```
template <class T> class LList_const_iterator {
public:
  //...
  LList_iterator(const Node<T>* p): node(p) { }
  //...
private:
  const Node<T>* node;
};
```

and change your typedef

```
// from
typedef LList_iterator<const T> const_iterator;
// to
typedef LList_const_iterator<T> const_iterator;
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess writing another iterator class would be the way to go.  This worked for me!